# Have variable perform an action in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

tiI am having a crash course lesson in VBA. I know the very basics of coding in general. I have tried to learn what variables and functions do. What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
 Sub test()
   Dim actionName As [action]
        actionName = Application.SendKey ("^v"), True
 ...

 Sleep 500
 actionName 'does an action of paste
 Sleep 1000
 actionName
 ...

End Sub
```

My goal is to save time typing long commands like Application.SendKeys() or ActiveCell(). How do I go about that? I saw that someone did that as a solution and I tried doing the variable but it didn't work. I asked a litle more specific question yesterday but it wasn't answered and gave me a completely different solution that I can't apply to other actions I want to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just define a Sub that does this? Create a new sub that all it does is call this `Application.SendKey ("^v"), True` and then call that on a timer

Comment: Crash course in VBA: don't rely on SendKeys method.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for a C-type define, which VBA does not support.  But you could easily use a Sub:

```
Sub test()
 ...

 Sleep 500
 actionName 'does an action of paste
 Sleep 1000
 actionName
 ...

End Sub

Sub actionName()
   Call Application.SendKey ("^v", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: I literally just added that as a comment above. I don't think `Call` is needed although it adds something to readability in this case

Comment: Why didn't I think of to do this sooner? So, to apply this. Say, I take `actionName()` into another sub like this: `Sub macro() sleep 500 actionName() sleep 500` Is that it?

Comment: And that both `Copy()` needs to be in the same module as `macro()` right?

Comment: Ah, it works so beautifully! I put the `copy()` in another module and then in `macro()` I called like this `call copy`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes to your first comment.  As far as being in the same module, it doesn't *have* to be.  You can call a sub in another module, provided it's not declared `Private`.

Comment: My first comment didn't work, `... Sleep 500 /next line actionName() /next line Sleep 500`. I needed to `call actionName` without the `()` after it, plus the `call`.